# Using different centring-methods within a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I've got following table which is almost what I wanted to have. But it would be much better if cells with text would be aligned vertical (only vertical) and cells with `--` would be aligned vertical & horizontal.

Does anyone has a suggestion on that issue?

Here is my table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis-ldpkg}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{tabular}{R{4cm}R{4cm}R{4cm}R{4cm}}     %<--- damit geht es jetzt auch ;)
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 4}} \\ 
\midrule

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Canada, France, Germany & Italy, Japan, United Kingdom, United States & -- & --\\

  Austria, Belgium, Netherlands, Switzerland & -- & Luxembourg & --\\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden & Denmark, Ireland & -- & --\\

  -- & Estonia, Hungary & Czech Republic, Slovenia & Poland, Slovak Republic \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Greece, Portugal, Spain & -- & -- & -- \\

  New Zealand & -- & Australia, Korea, Turkey & Israel \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case it's sufficient to override the `\raggedright` declaration, so

```
\newcommand{\nodata}{\centering\arraybackslash --}
```

will do the trick. Sample row:

```
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
  Canada, France, Germany &
  Italy, Japan, United Kingdom, United States &
  \nodata &
  \nodata \
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks egreg! Your approach has the advantage of using less code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

please use only packages which are part of any TeX-distribution!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\Ctr[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\cellcolor[gray]{#1}}c}{--}}
\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{R{4cm}R{4cm}R{4cm}R{4cm}}\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 4}} \\\midrule
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Canada, France, Germany & Italy, Japan, United Kingdom, United States 
          & \Ctr{0.9} & \Ctr{0.9} \\
  Austria, Belgium, Netherlands, Switzerland & \Ctr{1} & Luxembourg & \Ctr{1} \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden & Denmark, Ireland & \Ctr{0.9} & \Ctr{0.9}\\
  \Ctr{1} & Estonia, Hungary & Czech Republic, Slovenia & Poland, Slovak Republic \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Greece, Portugal, Spain & \Ctr{0.9} & \Ctr{0.9} & \Ctr{0.9} \\ 
  New Zealand & \Ctr{1} & Australia, Korea, Turkey & Israel \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Herbert. Worked perfect!
What did you mean by "please use only packages which are part of any TeX-distribution!"?

Comment: The `classicthesis-ldpkg` package has been dropped in the more recent versions of the `classicthesis` bundle.